# How can I maintain several Google Sign-In sessions alive to allow users to switch accounts without logging out?

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm currently trying to build an 'account switching' feature for my iOS App that uses Google Sign-In (with YouTube scopes to get YouTube channel data) & Firebase Authentication.

At the moment, if users want to switch accounts, they have to log out and log back in with another Google account, which is not great from a UX perspective.

My end goal is to allow users to log in with several channels and then choose the YouTube channel they want to see data for, from inside the app, without logging out and back in.

**Is there a way to maintain several OAuth sessions alive to let user easily switch between accounts?**

I have thought of storing the user's access token locally in a dictionary that would map channel ids with the relevant token but I'm not sure if that will be enough to maintain the state properly or if it will lead to a bunch of bugs.

Any ideas or suggestions are more than welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With Firebase Authentication, there can only be one signed in user at a time.  The SDK can't manage multiple signins at once.  The prior user needs to be signed out at the time a new signin is processed.